# RStudio not detecting MikTeX

Tags: miktex2.9, rstudio

I am having some trouble using MikTeX (v2.9) on windows 7 (64 bit) with RStudio (v1.1.447; R v 3.5.0). Despite the fact that I have installed the complete MikTeX, RStudio keeps telling me that no LaTex tool has been found when trying to knit any `rmd` document.

I’ve tried the answer given in a similar post ([RStudio Can't Find pdflatex On Windows 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231595/rstudio-cant-find-pdflatex-on-windows-7)) by running

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MikTex 2.9\\miktex\\bin", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

and it does not work.

It is funny because I have the same conficuration on another machine (though versions might differ) and it works smoothly. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to run into this problem every few months when deploying RStudio and MikTeX for co-workers. Here are some remedies:

1. Uninstalling everything. Then reinstall MikTeX, R, and RStudio, in that order, by right-clicking the installation files and selecting "Run as Administrator".
2. Carefully double check / VISIT the path in your

   ```
   Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTex 2.9\miktex\bin", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
   ```

   command. Sometimes there is an additional `bin64` subfolder that contains the required files. (I don't know why this is. Perhaps it happens if the installer contained both versions.)
3. When I don't have administrator privileges, I sometimes add the `Sys.setenv` command to the first line of the first chunk.
4. Try using Yihui's TinyTeX software. It has a number of great features that integrate well with RStudio. To use it, simply install the package and run the command:

   ```
   tinytex::install_tinytex()
   ```
5. Lastly, if you're working on a PC, I recommend installing the PERL programming language. It enables **knitr** to crop your .pdf images.